# PHP script using file_get_contents() running too long

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a PHP script, run via cron, that iterates through a list of sites and gathers data for each site using file_get_contents() against an API URL, then stores this data in a MySQL database. This script runs for 60 different site and we're seeing up to 5MB of serialized PHP data for each URL pull.

The system works swimmingly on my local MAMP server but, as soon as it's placed on a remote server, it stops behaving reliably. Sometimes it pulls and stores data but stores less records than the local server. It also finishes with a 504 Gateway error. On a different server, it simply doesn't finish at all. We've upped all the time limits in php.ini and compared what I have locally with the remote server and not seeing anything that stands out.

Is there any way to get a PHP script with these multiple repeated actions to run in a more "piecewise" way? Is there any way to "reset the timer" after each site runs? It need to be automated but setting up a cron against each site (3 URLs per site, 60 sites) just sounds like a nightmare to manage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turns out that both remote (shared) servers were shutting the process down before completion. Moving this to a VPS and switching the cron to just execute as PHP, as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be caused due to reaching the limit of threads of PHP or the web server, it also may be due to rules in the server about number of connections per unit of time.

If you can split the load and execute those cron jobs at different moments, you will get better results

Comment: This is what I'm thinking is the problem but I'm not able/capable of seeing what settings to tweak.

My thought was that chunking the process would help the server and be a better way to do this, since we could have 100+ sites to run this for but I didn't want to have multiple URLs in cron if I could help it.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `sleep($interval)` between each call to a remote site url? I don't think this scenario is very likely, web servers are very good at handling requests, and only making three, regardless of how fast, would be fine. More likely the API has some downstream resource contention going on (DB, file, etc).

Comment: well, you still may do it for a while to test the theory. Remember that a 504 is basically a log delay in the connection.

Answer (score 2):

If it takes that long to run, don't run it through the web server. You've already got a cron job, so just set the cron job up to run the script directly (*e.g*, `/usr/bin/php /home/path/to/cronjob.php`).

Comment: This could be the ticket... any more information? I'm new to setting up cron (if it's a simple RTFM, that's a fair response)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running network diagnostics from the remote server to the pages you're trying to access (Ping, DNS checks, Wget)? If the responses aren't positive (HTTP 200 Codes) file_get_contents may take a long time to timeout, or the site being queried could be taking a long time to respond. If you don't want to wait for failures, you can try to set the [stream context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#82527) with an appropriate timeout.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did set a longer timeout using a stream context and the URLs are functioning fine when called by themselves. They can take a long time to come back (30 seconds at most, only on URL taking that long) and it's a robust API so I get a response regardless, even if it's a failure (which I catch and log).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following in your `php.ini` settings file for consistency between servers; any one of them could explain the difference in behavior:

- timeouts
- execution time allowance
- memory limits
- packet sizes
- enabled/disabled extensions/modules (e.g. curl, mysql, etc.)

Comment: These, for the most part, are the same or higher on the remote server.